# Android Studio imports

Tags: android-studio, import

I'm creating a new project in Android Studio. I'm used to development in Eclipse, and I can simply hover on symbols that are not resolved and I'm able to import the dependencies.

Now when I hover on the symbols, I'm simply informed "Cannot resolve symbol X" with no option to import the dependency, even for simple ones like TextView. How do I auto resolve/import these symbols?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to place the cursor anywhere inside a class name (either by clicking with the mouse or moving the cursor with the arrow keys) then press Alt-Enter or right click. Usually the first option will be to import the class. You can also press Ctrl-Alt-O to optimize imports. I know this will remove unused imports and I **think** it will add missing imports.